# WebView rendering with MathJax very slow

Tags: android, performance, webview, cdn, mathjax

I am passing an HTML string containing Tex-formatted math to a WebView, which uses the MathJax library (delivered through a CDN) to render the webpage. The problem is, the app takes a long time to complete this whole process. On my Galaxy S7 edge on a good wifi connection, it takes almost 2 minutes to render even a very short string, such as $$X^2$$. My question is,

1. Which part of the program is actually responsible for such delay?
2. How to improve it?

Code:

```
package com.example.mutas.mathjaxpilot;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String front = "<html>" +
                "    <head>" +
                "        <script src=\'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML\' async></script>" +
                "    </head>" +
                "    <body>";

        final String back = " </body>" +
                "</html>" ;


        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        editText.setOnClickListener(
                new EditText.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String content = editText.getText().toString();
                        content = front + "\\( " + content + " \\)" + back;
                        webView.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
                    }
                }
        );


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                    1);
        }
        //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to tell, what causes such delays. What I would do is to isolate the problem, reduce the code step by step, until it does nothing more than starting up a blank app.

One thing I would try at the very beginning is to avoid the web request. Since this is a locally installed app, you could deliver the "MathJax.js" library as resource with your application, this way you can spare the web request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no">
    ...
    <script src="file:///android_asset/html/MathJax.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: The size of the library itself is almost 65 mb, so I would like to avoid adding the whole library in the app.

Comment: Seems we have found the culprit then, this is even more a reason to load it locally. An alternative way could be to copy the MathJax library to your own website and write an interface/api to use it. You would then e.g. make an Ajax call to your website, passing a string and retrieveing the result. This way you don't need the MathJax library on the device at all.

Comment: Update: despite the large size of the library, I have added it to the app, and there has been a significant improvement in the rendering speed. The whole process is now almost instantaneous.